# cron job doesn't execute docker command

Tags: linux, bash, docker, cron

I'm facing weird behavior on setting up cronjob.
I'm trying to execute simple `docker run` command at specific time every day, everything except docker is working, but docker command like just ignored or skipped.

I've tried to put command directly in crontab

`6 4 * * * docker run -it --rm -e EMAIL=email@gmail.com -e PASS=SOMEPASS docker_image`

Doesn't work. Then I tried to echo to some file to see if it actually triggered

`6 4 * * * echo "works" > file.txt && docker run -it --rm -e EMAIL=email@gmail.com -e PASS=SOMEPASS docker_image`

Echo is working, but docker still not executed. I also tried to save output from the docker to the file, but file is empty.

`6 4 * * * docker run -it --rm -e EMAIL=email@gmail.com -e PASS=SOMEPASS docker_image > file.log`

Then I moved the entire command to the bash script and run in manually to confirm command is correct and it works, so I've put this script file to cron, also added `echo`

`40 4 * * * /root/script.sh >> /root/file.log` (/root is a home folder)

Nothing is working, I tried to update bash file and put echo before and after docker command, and I see the result of those 2 (START,DONE), but docker still not executed and skipped.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "START"
docker run -it --rm -e EMAIL=email@gmail.com -e PASS=SOMEPASS docker_image
echo "DONE"
```

I've tried with sudo in crontab, still no result.
I've checked `/var/log/syslog` file and see that cron triggered

`Oct 16 04:40:01 ubuntu-8gb-nbg1-1 CRON[433288]: (root) CMD (sudo /root/script.sh >> /root/file.log)`

Here's output of permissions on the file

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        176 Oct 16 04:38 script.sh`

Please help with understanding what I missed or how to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `-it` flags from docker command since the Crontab doesn't support terminal (you may add `-d` flag to your docker command optionally if you want the container run and continue in the background).

```bash
6 4 * * * docker run --rm -e EMAIL=email@gmail.com -e PASS=SOMEPASS docker_image
```

or

```bash
6 4 * * * docker run -d --rm -e EMAIL=email@gmail.com -e PASS=SOMEPASS docker_image
```

Comment: thank you. `it` was the issue :D

Answer (score 0):

Is your user in docker group? Can you run docker --ps on bash. Does cronjob belong to root?

Comment: yes, user in docker group. the issue was in previous answer fro Vab